# Get an Image from a Rich Text Area Field (salesforce)

Tags: node.js, salesforce, jsforce

I am facing some problem with retrieving the images from Salesforce fields.

I am trying to follow [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_rich_text_image_retrieve.htm), but I am not able to get the binary form of the image.

Following is how my data looks:

```
{
  "attributes": {
      "type": "lord",
      "url": "/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/lord/000000GrWZAA0"
  },
  "Id": "000000GrWZAA0",
  "Solution__c": "<img alt=\"User-added image\" height=\"187\" src=\"https://company--d.na6.content.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=ka380033330GrWZ&amp;feoid=00N82222205DIbz&amp;refid=0EM45430000kCBr\" width=\"500\"></img>"
}
```

So referrring the [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_rich_text_image_retrieve.htm) , I created a GET request as mentioned in the Salesforce documentation:

```
https://company.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/lord/000000GrWZAA0/richTextImageFields/Solution__c/0EM45430000kCBr/body
```

with header:

```
Authorization: Bearer token
```

After making a request, I get the following error:

```
[
    {
        "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
        "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
    }
]
```

Can someone please throw some light on what am I missing. everything looks good to me, but I am guessing I am missing some silly thing in this easy piece of code.

Also, I have looked upon many other threads about accessing, but since I am using NodeJS (REST API), I am not finiding the best solution that I can proceed with. The one I am referring is the above one which I am stuck at.

It would be great if someone can help me with this or maybe direct me towards an other way to access this image link to public.
I am using: NodeJS, and NPM Module [JSFORCE](https://jsforce.github.io/) for my implementation.

TIA

Comment: Hi @RDoonds,

I am facing the same issue, have you resolved this? please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try changing the version from 42.0 to **43.0** and also remove the '/body' part from the request. I think that should work.

```
https://company.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/lord/000000GrWZAA0/richTextImageFields/Solution__c/0EM45430000kCBr
```